# Can a structure like this exist?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure

I was studying carbon compounds and this popped up in my mind:

[image: This is what came to my mind while studying]

Comment: You can try googling "[3.3.3.3]fenestrane" or "pyramidane" for some info

Comment: Wikipedia says this: ``Pyramidane ([3.3.3.3]fenestrane) is the smallest possible fenestrane, and has never been synthesised``

Comment: *fenetre* is french for *window*. nice name for this compound!

Comment: If that matter window is  fenestram in latin. I never understood why there are continuing references to French words. Surely french chemists did a lot. But the assonance to a french word will be likely found for the same word in all neo latin languages. Just to say that the history of a named compound might or not have to do with France or french chemists.

Comment: @samjoe FYI _fenestra_ is window in Latin.

Comment: hold your horses @alchimista! I was just sharing my (little?) knowledge. I am not even french btw :)

Comment: @samjoe nothing specific to your comment! I read often such comparison to french here and elsewhere.  I wanted to say not to assume chemical-historic motivations behind.  :)

Comment: Boron clusters of square antiprism geometry capped with carbon atoms (axial positions) is the closest thing that comes to mind (e.g. in your structure 4 vertices of the square are B atoms). But as of now, there is no known crystal structures of the composition you've drawn.